# Google Analytics Data api (beta) returning incomplete data sometimes

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm working with data from Google analytics GA4 in python, using `RunReportRequest` call. The issue I'm facing is that sometimes the script returns complete data with all values, but sometimes dimensions come null, mostly custom dimensions. BTW in all API calls I still had available quota.

I've noticed this behavior even scheduling the script execution multiple times a day, and haven't been able to pinpoint what could possible be the cause since the script conditions are pretty much the same.

The script I'm using is similar to this one:

```
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient, DateRange, RunReportRequest, Dimension, Metric
import os

client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
property_id = os.environ.get('PROPERTY_ID')


def download_ga_data(start_date, end_date, limit=int(1e6)):
    request = RunReportRequest(property=f"properties/{property_id}",
                               dimensions=[Dimension(name=x) for x in ['customEvent:myCustomEvent', 'eventName']],
                               metrics=[Metric(name="averageSessionDuration")],
                               date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date)],
                               limit=limit,
                               return_property_quota=True,
                               keep_empty_rows=False)
    response = client.run_report(request)
    return response
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe it could be some delay issue
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9333790

Comment: You are not using the Google analytics reporting api you are using the Google analytics data api.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data being returned and what you would expect to be returned?

Comment: Data api. I'm editing the question.

Comment: An example: https://pastebin.com/9JyLx9QQ

Comment: i am encountering a similar problem. for the same dimension and metrics, when date ranges between 2022-11-01 and 2023-01-31 i get 5 rows. for dates between 2022-12-01 and 2023-01-31, i get 31 even though the former is a superset of the latter.